# Why does text display symbols on mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, fonts

I have a page that looks completely fine on desktop, but looks terrible on mobile. I've asked some people and they have said that the font (*MS PGothic*) isn't compatible with mobile, but when I changed it to *Arial* it still displays weird symbols? Is there a way to fix it?

Here is the code! ([Live preview](https://katsuki.neocities.org/))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>☆</title>
  <style>
    div.main {
      font-family: "ms pgothic";
      line-height: 110%;
    }
    div.header {
      font-family: "ms pgothic";
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <p><i>stay close to me, don’t go</i></p>
    <p><a href="//example.com">twitter</a>
    <a href="//example.com">tumblr</a>
    <a href="//example.com">curiouscat</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <ul>
      <li>tome (toh-meh)</li>
      <li>they/them, non-binary</li>
      <li>18↓</li>
      <li>february 8, aquarius</li>
      <li>se asian</li>
      <li>socal</li>
      <li><a href="/example.html">personality</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="header">
    <a href="/byf.html">byf</a>
    <a href="/ids.html">ids</a>
    <a href="/ccs.html">ccs</a>
    <a href="/bl.html">blacklist</a>
    <a href="/i.html">interests</a>
    <a href="/f.html">favs</a>
    <a href="/c.html">credit</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Arial is not a font supported in any mobile devices. You should provide a url to the font using @font-face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining the `font-family`, you should provide at least one other font for systems without the first font to fall back on. It's recommended that your last `font-family` declaration either be `serif` or `sans-serif`. You could try changing your code to:

`font-family: 'ms pgothic', serif;`

You should also be declaring `charset` in the `<head>` of your HTML. For example:

`<meta charset="utf-8">`

Answer (score 0):

Mobile must not have the font built-in. I don't see the link to the font anywhere, so that's why I'm guessing it's built-in. Try downloading the font, then go to http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp and learn how to integrate it into your website. If you're using Windows, you can just do [WINDOWS_BUTTON + R] and type in "Fonts" without the quotes. Then, search for the font you want, and copy and paste it onto your desktop where you can then upload it to your server. After, you can follow the steps provided by w3schools.com.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add <meta charset="utf-8"> into the <head>. The charset meta will ensure the symbols display correctly.